# limit of 10,000 tables for an instance or per database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#table_limit

"Cloud SQL for MySQL has a limit of 10,000 tables for an instance. Too many tables can significantly impact the performance of a Cloud SQL instance. Instances that exceed this limit are not covered by the SLA."

We have a Mysql instance that has one database for each of our customer using a unique subdomain. Databases are pretty much identical expect for permissions. Each database has about 70 Tables and currently we have about 120 databases (about 8400 tables total) all under one 4x16 mysql instance. Currently we are just creating a new database for each new customer.

I'm concentered about the 10000 limits in googles documentation for each instance. I'm not sure if that's stated incorrectly or the that limit applies at the database level and not at the instance level.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the link that you provided (and even it's not clear), if you go above the limit of 10k tables per instance (it's mentioned instance, not database), your instance won't be covered by the SLA.

However, you don't have a hard limit that prevent you to add mode than 10k tables. use it at own risk, if you have major issue, Google support could tell you: you didn't follow the recommendation to keep a number of table acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I really appreciated. In my research I have seen that Amazon Aurora database doesn't have those limitation and we don't really have to change anything in the app to use that. Do you know if GCP has something similar to Aurora ? I have looked at cloud spanner but that looks like its major overwrite on the app side.

Comment: there isn't autoscalling database like Aurora on Google Cloud (and take care of Aurora perf also). The problem here isn't the technical limitation, but the limit of Google Cloud commitment. Above 10k table, you haven't SLA, but the database continue to work. You can use Spanner, and your rework should be low. JDBC connector are compliant, just take care of the table relation (must be "simple"). The issue with spanner is the cost: about x10 that Cloud SQL. More powerful, but much more expensive.